# How to cast the value from the retrieved value from Database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, database

I have one database table which contains multiple columns are there with different data types,one of the column is `currency` which is stored inside a database  as an `integer`.

i have one API which is used for retrieving all the values from the database and displayed in UI,in my UI level they are accepting `currency` value as a string, is there any way to send the currency value as a `string` without changing the current structure of a database.,please give me some idea how to do this one..

Comment: Something to think about: currency value in `integer` might be an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: @user3532758 well depends, you can save 1$ as an integer of 100 to manage decimals and avoid infinite decimal issue and all the floating-point numbers operations issues too. it's the best solution in that case.

Comment: @N69S yes as long as it's a thought out decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways. one is to use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'currency' => 'string',
    ];
}
```

Another radical solution would be to remove the module mysqlnd so everything is returned as string.

Comment: This solution is stored as a string inside database or it should convert as a string after fetching the details

Comment: @user17426459 even if you send it as a string to the database, the field in an integer. would not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `strval()` function of PHP

```php
$currency = SomeModel::all()->map(function ($someRow) {
   return $someRow->currrency = strval($someRow->currency);
}
```

Btw, The proper way to do this is using Accessors

```php
public function getCurrency() {
    return strval($this->currency);
}
```

Now, every time you get currency from your model, you will get the string casted value.

```
echo $model->currency;
// "10"
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for more